# Recyclerview is not recycling views properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am loading images from URL into horizontal recyclerview using Picasso as:

```java
public class pIndicatorAdaptor extends
         RecyclerView.Adapter<pIndicatorAdaptor.IndicatorViewHolder> {

   //constructor and other stuff

   @Override
   public IndicatorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int vType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.i_item, parent, false);
        return new IndicatorViewHolder(view);
    }
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IndicatorViewHolder holder, int position) {
        picasso.load(images.get(position).getSrc()).fit().centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView, null);
    }

    class IndicatorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;

        IndicatorViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the result like this,The bottom horizontal recyclerview is where I am loading images:

[image: Error GIF]

Answer (score 1):

when you keep scroll the recycler view like that,it's load the image every time and ofcourse it took alot of time to load the image.i think you should use glide on this because glide is really good on load the image from cache ( if exist) ;)

Comment: Agree with shadow. Using third-party image rendering library (Glide or Picasso) will solve this issue

Comment: @AnkurMishra  Am I missing something here? I am actually using Picasso to load those images.

Comment: This of course has little to do with Glide or picasso.. setIsRecyclable(false) is  low cost solution .